# PUT request from Postman is not being received by Java Controller

Tags: rest, postman, put

I've written multiple REST Endpoints in my Controller [GET, POST and PUT].

GET and POST calls are working fine. But when I try to hit PUT request from Postman, my java controller is not able to receive that request. There is no error message. Response body is empty. Response code in Postman is 200, OK.

Here is my PUT Endpoint which is not able to get request from Postman:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/devRegistration")
public Object deviceRegistration(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,  
        @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> jsonBody ){

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    System.out.println("jsonBody = "+jsonBody);
    devService.deviceRegistration(httpRequest, jsonBody);

    return response;
}
```

Here is my GET Endpoint which is working fine:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/checkRegistration")
public void checkRegistration(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,  
        @RequestParam("appId") String appId, @RequestParam("offset") String offset  ){

    Map<String, Object> jsonBody = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    jsonBody.put("appId", appId);
    jsonBody.put("offset", offset);
    service.checkRegistration(httpRequest, jsonBody);
}
```

Postman URL with Headers and Body for PUT request is :

```
https://localhost:8443/api/device/devRegistration
In Body:
app_Id : some value
offset : some value

Headers are:

RequestHeader
Content-Type
Authorization
MobileHeader
SessionToken
```

But, System.out.println() is not being executed in PUT Endpoint.

Let me know, if any other info. is required.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Actually, I need to pass the params in the Body as raw form instead of form-data in Postman.

It worked now.